# How to create a vector with the pattern [1 2 5 6 9 10 13 14 17 18 ....] in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

Assume that we want to create a vector with the pattern:

```
[1   3   5   7   9]
```

We could easily write

```
1:2:10
```

But what should I write if I want to have this pattern:

```
[1 2 5 6 9 10 13 14 17 18 ....]
```

?

The idea behind this is that I have a long column matrix:

```
[-0.41416   0.37756  -3.39666  -0.42352   0.83481  -0.66782  -0.75471   0.54008  -0.60284 -1.43141  -1.10128  -0.18244]
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
[-0.41416   0.37756 0 0  -3.39666  -0.42352 0 0   0.83481  -0.66782 0 0  -0.75471   0.54008 0 0 -0.60284 -1.43141 0 0 -1.10128  -0.18244 0 0]
```

For every 2 values, I want to add two zeros.

Here is how I have solved it if I only want to have 0 zero between every value.

```
l = length(g);
nu = rows(g);
G = zeros(nu, l*nu);
for i = 1:nu
  G(i, i:nu:l*nu-1+i) = g(i, 1:l);
end
g = G;
```

That code will turn this pattern

```
   [1.4392e-04   5.6149e-07   1.4572e-04  -1.1104e-05   1.4720e-04  -3.3176e-05   1.4836e-04
   2.4174e-04   6.5988e-06   2.7917e-04   5.3787e-06   3.1924e-04   1.0706e-06   3.6204e-04]
```

Into this pattern:

```
   [0.000221   0.000000  -0.000420   0.000000   0.000570   0.000000  -0.000418   0.000000
   0.000000   0.017647   0.000000  -0.002033   0.000000   0.017248   0.000000  -0.001855]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack two row vectors (the second equal to one plus the first) and then reshape it:

```matlab
>> a=[1:4:17];
>> b=reshape(vertcat(a,a+1),1,[])

b =

     1     2     5     6     9    10    13    14    17    18
```

The same idea extends to your second "reason behind this" example:

```matlab
>> c=[-0.41416   0.37756  -3.39666  -0.42352   0.83481  -0.66782  -0.75471   0.54008  -0.60284 -1.43141  -1.10128  -0.18244];
>> d=reshape(c,2,[]);
>> e=reshape(vertcat(d,0*d),1,[])

e =

  Columns 1 through 12

   -0.4142    0.3776         0         0   -3.3967   -0.4235         0         0    0.8348   -0.6678         0         0

  Columns 13 through 24

   -0.7547    0.5401         0         0   -0.6028   -1.4314         0         0   -1.1013   -0.1824         0         0
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of answering the question in the title, I'll show how to accomplish the task you actually want to accomplish: insert two zeros after every two data values.

To do this, we reshape (this is essentially free, no data is copied) the vector to have 2xN elements. We now add two rows of zeros, and reshape the matrix to a column vector again:

```matlab
M = [-0.41416   0.37756  -3.39666  -0.42352   0.83481  -0.66782  -0.75471   0.54008  -0.60284 -1.43141  -1.10128  -0.18244].';

M = reshape(M,2,[]);
M = [M;zeros(size(M))];
M = reshape(M,[],1);
M = M(1:end-2);      % remove the last two zeros, which we don't want
```

Of course this only works for even-sized arrays. For an odd-sized array, we add a zero first, then remove it after:

```matlab
M = [-0.41416   0.37756  -3.39666  -0.42352   0.83481  -0.66782  -0.75471   0.54008  -0.60284 -1.43141  -1.10128].';

M = reshape([M;0],2,[]); % note we add a zero here
M = [M;zeros(size(M))];
M = reshape(M,[],1);
M = M(1:end-3);          % remove the last three zeros, which we don't want
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any math for this; you can indeed take advantage of the *MAT* part of *MATLAB*, as follows:

- generate the array of the odd-indexed elements of the desired array,
- add 1 to it to obtain the array of the even-indexed elements,
- concatenate the two rows vertically, thus obtaining a matrix with two rows,
- vectorize the matrix columnwise,
- transpose it, if you really need a row.

```matlab
n = 100;
x = 1:4:n;
x = [x; x + 1];
x = x(:)';
```

This generates an even number of elements in the outcoming vector. If you need an odd number, use the same code, with appropriate `n`, and change the last line to this:

```matlab
x = x(1:end-1)';
```

Answer (score 2):

**An answer trying to solve this for arbitrary length, not relying on the length to be dividable by 2 or 4.**

When approaching such tasks, I like to describe the pattern in a short textual or mathematical way, which usually leads to something I can implement. Here "all numbers from 1 to n which have a remainder of 1 or 2 when divided by 4"

```
>> n=9;
>> find(ismember(mod(1:n,4),[1,2]))

ans =

     1     2     5     6     9
```

Which allows you to set the highest value `n`. If you instead want to set `m` the number of elements in your list, I would use the following code:

```
>> m = 7;

>> [1:m]*2-(mod([1:m],2)==0)-1

ans =

    1     2     5     6     9    10    13
```

The idea behind this, your pattern is something like 2 4 6 8, decremented by 1 and then again every odd position decremented by 1. This is probably more suitable for your indexing operation:

```
x=rand(7,1);
m=numel(x);
pattern=[1:m]*2-(mod([1:m],2)==0)-1;
y(pattern)=x;
```

which returns:

```
y =

    0.9572    0.4854         0         0    0.8003    0.1419         0         0    0.4218    0.9157         0         0    0.7922
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view

```
[1 2 5 6 9 10 13 14 17 18 ....]
```

as the following sum:

```
  [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...] + [1 1 5 5 9 9 13 13 ...]
= [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...] + [0 0 4 4 8 8 12 12 ...] + [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...]
= [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...] + 4*[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 ...] + [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...]
```

Each of those chunks should be easier to create:

```
[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...] = mod(0:1:9, 2)
[0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 ...] = floor(0.5 * (0:1:9))
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...] = ones(1, 10)
```

Putting it together:

```
>> mod(0:1:9, 2) + 4*floor(0.5*(0:1:9)) + ones(1,10)
ans =
    1    2    5    6    9   10   13   14   17   18
```

But going to the second part of your question, there is an easier way to solve it if your goal is to insert two zeroes after every two elements. Start by reshaping your long array as an 2-by-(n/2) matrix:

```
>> y = reshape(x, 2, 6)
y =
  -0.41416  -3.39666   0.83481  -0.75471  -0.60284  -1.10128
   0.37756  -0.42352  -0.66782   0.54008  -1.43141  -0.18244
```

Now insert two rows of zeros:

```
>> z = [y; zeros(2, 6)]
z 
  -0.41416  -3.39666   0.83481  -0.75471  -0.60284  -1.10128
   0.37756  -0.42352  -0.66782   0.54008  -1.43141  -0.18244
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Then reshape it back to a 1-dimensional array:

```
>> w = reshape(z, 1, 24)
w =
 Columns 1 through 7:
  -0.41416   0.37756   0.00000   0.00000  -3.39666  -0.42352   0.00000
 Columns 8 through 14:
   0.00000   0.83481  -0.66782   0.00000   0.00000  -0.75471   0.54008
 Columns 15 through 21:
   0.00000   0.00000  -0.60284  -1.43141   0.00000   0.00000  -1.10128
 Columns 22 through 24:
  -0.18244   0.00000   0.00000
```